# Adding adview(admob) to linearlayout dynamically

Tags: java, android, adview

I want to display on the top of activity which consist of scrollable tableview. The content and number of rows are dynamic in tableview.

when I try to run the below code, It shows me table until when the ad is loaded, but when the ad is loaded the tableview disappears. I dont understand why this is happening.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="***********"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/table_layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <TableRow>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/left_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:padding="5dip"
                    android:text="Code" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/middle_text"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                    android:padding="5dip"
                    android:text="Name of Company" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/right_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0"
                    android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                    android:padding="5dip"
                    android:text="1.3" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default [orientation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android%3aorientation) of `LinearLayout` is horizontal. When ads is loaded, all contents shifts to the right. You should set orientation of the `LinearLayout` to vertical. Add this to your `LinearLayout`:

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yout tablelayout width is fillparent. Change it to wrap content.